# Is there any way to make a fixed background in one section of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you know, background-attachment doesn't work with mobile devices. For a desktop I use it, but for Android and IOS I have no idea how I should to create a parallax effect.

I thought about **position: fixed**, however **overflow: hidden** with it also doesn't work at all, because an object becomes attached to the viewport.

As well I tried earlier to do it by JS using **background-position-y**, which took value **window.scrollY**, though it's laggy too (positioning happens with a delay and sometimes background is shaking).

JS:

```
function parallax() {
    document.body.style = `--check: ${window.scrollY}px`;
    requestAnimationFrame(parallax)
}
requestAnimationFrame(parallax);
```

CSS:

```
background-position-y: var(--check);
```

I am out of ideas what to do. Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance!